# Using Invoke() to show Form from Threading.Time() thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, .net-3.5

I have the following:

```
  public static Form1 MainForm = new Form1();
    static ManualResetEvent _running = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    [MTAThread]
    private static void Main()
    {
        int startin = 60 - DateTime.Now.Second;
        var t = new System.Threading.Timer(o => Analyze(),
            null, startin*1000, 60000);

        _running.WaitOne();
    }

    public static void Analyze()
    {
        Action a = new Action(() => MainForm.ShowDialog());
        MainForm.Invoke(a);
    }
```

I'm having a hard time attempting to display the only form I have - MainForm.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are trying to solve a chicken-and-egg problem.  The Invoke() method cannot possibly figure out which thread might be the UI thread of the program until *after* the window is created.  Which the basic flaw here that you don't actually have a UI thread.  Get ahead by not treating the creation of a user interface as an afterthought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `MainForm.Invoke` you're telling the form to schedule the operation provided to be run from the application loop the form is running in.  When you're calling that method your form *has no application loop*, and as such there's nothing to run the operation that you've scheduled, so it doesn't get run.

Ironically enough the operation you're trying to schedule in the application's loop is the creation of the application loop.

You'll need to start your application loop (using `Application.Run`), create your form, and then once you've done that you can schedule work for that application to perform.

Comment: I originally removed `Application.Run(form);` In order to display the form on demand, Which works if i Manually do `MainForm.ShowDialog();` within `main()`. But what I'm trying to achieve here is the ability to display this form only if a certain condition is met in another application. I'm using Windows Mobile CE 6.5 Pro.